# SQL Server Rows to Multi-Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE SourceTbl ([Code] varchar(3), [Total] decimal, [Date] datetime );

INSERT INTO SourceTbl ([Code], [Total], [Date]) 
VALUES ('AA', 100, '2012-12-01'), ('AA', 200, '2013-02-01'), ('BB', 50, '2012-01-01');
```

A simple select will return

```
Code | Total | Date
'AA' | 100   | 2012-12-01
'AA' | 200   | 2013-02-01
'BB' | 50    | 2012-01-01
```

but what I need is the following

```
Code | Total | Date       | Total | Date
'AA  | 200   | 2013-02-01 | 100   | 2012-12-01
'BB  | 50    | 2012-01-01 | null  | null
```

I have been trying to do this using a PIVOT operator but without success (based on the question [SQL Server Pivot multiple columns based on one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023479/sql-server-pivot-multiple-columns-based-on-one-column)).

Using that example, all I get are two rows with null values.

The Total/Date columns can be repeated 13 times and they must be ordered by Date DESC.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f37a1/2

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `PIVOT` + `Row_NUMBER()` to the rescue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need just two columns:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by Code order by Date) as rn
    from SourceTbl
)
select
    code,
    max(case when rn = 1 then Total end) as Total1,
    max(case when rn = 1 then Date end) as Date1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then Total end) as Total2,
    max(case when rn = 2 then Date end) as Date2
from cte
group by code
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f37a1/10)

dynamic solution:

```
declare @stmt nvarchar(max)

;with cte as (
     select distinct
         cast(row_number() over(partition by Code order by Date) as nvarchar(max)) as rn
     from SourceTbl
)
select @stmt = isnull(@stmt + ', ', '') + 
    'max(case when rn = ' + rn + ' then Total end) as Total' + rn + ',' +
    'max(case when rn = ' + rn + ' then Date end) as Date' + rn 
from cte
order by rn

select @stmt = '
    with cte as (
        select *, row_number() over(partition by Code order by Date) as rn
        from SourceTbl
    )
    select
        code, ' + @stmt + ' from cte group by code'

exec sp_executesql
    @stmt = @stmt
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f37a1/14)

Comment: Awesome work! Never knew you could dynamically add columns like that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to dynamically create columns in your result set?

If you had a third record of 'AA' with a total of 300 and the date of 03/01/2013 would you that mean you would want something like this displayed?

```
Code | Total | Date       | Total | Date      | Total | Date
 AA  | 200   | 2013-02-01 | 100   | 2012-12-01| 300   | 03-01-13
 BB  | 50    | 2012-01-01 | null  | null      | null  | null
```

Comment: This should be a comment rather than answer

Comment: Yes i  can have up to 13 total/date combinations.